# When exactly do normal init blocks execute in java

Tags: java

```
class Bird {
    {
        System.out.print("b1 ");
    }

    public Bird() {
        System.out.print("b2 ");
    }
}

class Raptor extends Bird {
    static {
        System.out.print("r1 ");
    }

    public Raptor() {
        System.out.print("r2 ");
    }

    {
        System.out.print("r3 ");
    }
    static {
        System.out.print("r4 ");
    }
}

class Hawk extends Raptor {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("pre ");
        new Hawk();
        System.out.println("hawk ");
    }
}
```

I'm preparing for Java OCA exam. Above code is from the book I'm studying right now. According to the answer the result should be

```
r1 r4 pre b1 b2 r3 r2 hawk
```

while I would expect it to be

```
pre r1 r4 b1 b2 r3 r2 hawk
```

taking into consideration these rules:

1. Static init blocks run when class is first loaded
2. Normal init blocks run right after all super constructors have run

Could someone please show me step by step how this happens? I can understand `r1` and `r4` to come before everything but why `pre` right after them?

Comment: [The JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2) explains the process of class initialization involving superclasses/superinterfaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the class `Hawk` is loaded, the class `Raptor` and `Bird` must also be loaded because, as they are the superclass(es), they are part of the definition of `Hawk`.  When the class is loaded the static initializers are run.  "static" really just means it is part of the class rather than instances of the class.

The next thing the JVM does is begin executing the `main` method.  It is static, so no instance is created yet.  That is why 'pre' is printed next.

Then the main method creates an instance of `Hawk`, which will invoke the constructor.  Prior to entry in the constructor method the non-static intializer blocks are executed, along with field initialization (which these classes do not have any), in order in the file.

After this it prints 'hawk' and exits.

---

*PS.  When writing code I avoid initializer blocks.  It is easier to read the code and understand it later when all the statements are in the constructor method.  An exception is to build constant collections (ie Maps) since Java doesn't really support it otherwise (unlike Python or JavaScript syntax for literal maps/dicts/objects).*

Comment: I've missed the key point that as main method is static no instance of the Hawk is created at program startup, so no constructor is invoked. And the only thing that would load (not construct an instance ) is the child class parents and their static fields and blocks. That is fine now.

Answer (score 1):

first class `Hawk` should loaded to run main method .but before Hawk get loaded super class `Raptor` should get loaded .so

first `Raptor` get loaded and static blocks of `Raptor`run and it prints `r1` and `r4`

Answer (score 1):

- First instruction in constructor is invoking constructor of its
  parent class super(params).
- Code in initializer block is executed after super() call .
- Static block is executed when it is fully loaded by JVM.

At first class `Hawk` is loaded.Since it extends `Raptor`, that class is also loaded.When `Raptor` is loaded, it executes static blocks in it.

Thus you get r`1 r4`

After that main method executes.Thus o/p becomes `r1 r4 pre`.

Then `Hawk` is loaded.On calling constructor of `Hawk`,`Raptor's` constructor is called.`Raptor's` constrcutor calls `Bird's` constructor.This loads the `Bird` class and static block inside `Bird` is executed followed by construtor.

Thus o/p becomes `r1 r4 pre b1 b2`

After `Bird's` constructor finishes, the r3 block is executed and `Raptor's` constructor finihes.

O/p becomes r1 r4 pre b1 b2 r3 r2 .

And finally last sysout is executed